# Pass object (List<string>) as part of Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am constructing a list of strings and then want to throw an exception and let the UI handle the list and create the error message for the user.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `let the UI parse the list` - Why is the UI responsible for that?

Comment: @HighCore: I think he just means formatting the list into something readable for a messagebox

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Exceptions contains [`Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property (which is a dictionary). It can be used to pass additional information:

```
try
{
    // throw new Exception
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // whatever
    e.Data["SomeData"] = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: And if you need to include the object in a throw statement (in case you want it to bubble up potentially several levels), you can just do `var e = new Exception("some error") { Data = { {"obj1", obj1}, {"obj2", obj2} } } }` and then `throw e`

Answer (score 37):

You can use the [`Exception.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property to pass arbitrary data but a better (cleaner) solution would be to create your own custom exception class derived from Exception and add whatever properties you need to it.

Sample code:

```
public class MyException: Exception
{
    public List<String> MyStrings { get; private set; }

    public MyException(List<String> myStrings)
    {
        this.MyStrings = myStrings;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the subclass idea as I prefer strong[er] typing.

Comment: strong typing is good, but the big advantage is cleaner and more obvious code when you try to handle the exception (using cascading catch statements)

Comment: Yeah, strong[er] typing :D

Comment: The microsoft article that supports this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx